# database postgresql doesn't create table

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I try to launch my flask application with postgresql But got the error thats seems like it couldn't create table I think I do all the configuration correct But Now Just Got this error I try to use different Role and different db But Nothing work so this is the error

PS: It was work very well But I accidently drop the database in postgresql and had to create new one

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError

ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column users.id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users... ^ 'SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.name AS users_name, users.age AS users_age, users.email AS users_email, users.bestfriend_id AS users_bestfriend_id \nFROM users \nWHERE users.name = %(name_1)s \n LIMIT %(param_1)s' {'name_1': u'orchid', 'param_1': 1}
```

config.py:

```
import os
CSRF_ENABLE = True
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MONKEYS_PAGE = 2

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = 'Thisismysecretkey'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL','postgresql+psycopg2://someuser:somepassword@localhost/myapp')
    print SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
```

__ init __.py :

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
lm = LoginManager()
lm.login_view = 'login'
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'layout.login'

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    db.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    # login_manager.user_loader(load_user)
    from .layout import layout as appr_blueprint
    # register our blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(appr_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    return app
```

manage.py:

```
import os
import unittest
import coverage
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from app import create_app
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from app import db
from app.model import Users

app = create_app(os.environ['FLASK_CONFIG'] or 'default')
magrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

@manager.command
def init_db():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()


@manager.command
def test():
    from subprocess import call
    call(['nosetests', '-v',
    '--with-coverage', '--cover-package=app', '--cover-branches',
    '--cover-erase', '--cover-html', '--cover-html-dir=cover'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
            manager.run()
```

Not sure do I need this file or Not?
when I run db_create.py will get the error

```
  raise RuntimeError('application not registered on db '
    RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

db_create.py:

```
    from app import db,model
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit(

)
```

Answer (score 0):

`db_create.py` is not part of the manage script that you wrote.  Therefore it's not creating an app and activating an app context.

```
from app import create_app, db

with create_app(os.environ['FLASK_CONFIG'] or 'default').app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

---

However, if you're using Alembic (Flask-Migrate in this case), never use `db.create_all`.  You should only ever use the migrations to set up the database: `python manage.py db upgrade`.